# MS Excel : how to compare a cell with comma separated values to a cell with comma separated values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I have a cell with value “app, beta, theta” and I want to see if a column filled with cells such as above contains my cell values.
So for example: a column AA has these cells : “app” ; “theta, app” ; “theta, app, beta” then my formula should return the index or cell number ‘AA3’ as the third cell has similar values to my cell. Please help

I tried using different approaches but I cannot seem to find one where it traverses through the column

Comment: Can you show us what it is you tried?

Answer (score 2):

This will give the *relative* position of the matched entry:

```
=XMATCH(
    TEXTJOIN("|", , SORT(TEXTSPLIT(A1, ", "))),
    BYROW(AA1:AA3, LAMBDA(ζ, TEXTJOIN("|", , SORT(TEXTSPLIT(ζ, ", "), , , 1))))
)
```

Comment: In case it matters, If there is more than one match, it only returns the first one. Regards

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

[image]

Formula in `E1`:

```
=XMATCH(1,BYROW(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(", "&TEXTSPLIT(C1,", ")&", ",", "&A1:A3&", ")),LAMBDA(a,--AND(a))))
```

**Note:** This would return the index of the 1st cell that would hold all cs-values *+ any additional values that may occur in the lookup-range!*

Comment: In case it matters, If there is more than one match, it only returns the first one. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative. The following one *ensures that If there is more than one match, additional rows will be returned*.

```
=LET(lk, SORT(TEXTSPLIT(C1,,", ")), in, A1:A3,FILTER(SEQUENCE(ROWS(in)),
 BYROW(in, LAMBDA(x,AND(TOROW(lk=SORT(TEXTSPLIT(x,,", ",,1)),2)))),"Not found"))
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]

Per `BYROW` iteration it compares lookup value `lk` (`C1` cell split by rows and sorted) with split and sorted row array for string `x`. Since the arrays can have different sizes, `TOROW` with the second input argument (`2`) removes `#N/A` values, otherwise it can return `#N/A`. In order to have a full match, each row comparison needs to be `TRUE`, so we use `AND` condition for that. Finally, we use the output of `BYROW` to filter the sequence of index positions of the input (`in`) via `FILTER`.